# Magento - salesOrderShipmentList by order_increment_id

Tags: c#, api, magento

I need to be able to retrieve an sales_order_shipment for a sales_order by the sales_order_increment_id. 
According to the Definitive Guide to Magento I am allowed to use the order_increment_id as a key in the method's filter, however when I do I get an error stating the key is unsupported.

**Here is the code I am using:**

```
  // Construct filter.
  var filters = new filters();
  var filterOrderId = new complexFilter
  {
    key = "order_increment_id",
    value = new associativeEntity() { key = "eq", value = orderIcrementId.ToString() }        
  };

  filters.complex_filter = new[] { filterOrderId };
  var shipments = apiService.salesOrderShipmentList(sSessionId, filters);
```

**Error Message:**

{"SQLSTATE[42S22]: Column not found: 1054 Unknown column 'order_increment_id' in 'where clause'"}

I can use other filters fine (order_id, created_at etc..) but I really need to be able to return a sales_order_shipment by the order_increment_id using the salesOrderShipmentList from the Magento API.

If you need any additional info, please ask.

Comment: Which version of Magento are you working against?

Comment: Version 1.6.1 community edition.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are stabbing at it wrong.  You are trying to look up shipments by order increment id, but that value is not available.  Your available value is "order_id".  You must use this.

Look up your order's id by using it's increment id, then filter the shipments by that.

```
private void GetShipments()
    {
        // Create the filter array
        filters theFilters = new filters();

        // get the order's id from its incrementId
        salesOrderEntity theOrder = this.mageObject.MageService.salesOrderInfo(this.mageObject.MageSessionId, this.Session["orderID"] as string);

        // Create the "C#" version of the associative array using a generic list
        List<associativeEntity> theEntities = new List<associativeEntity>
            {
                new associativeEntity { key = "order_id", value = theOrder.order_id } 
            };

        // Make the generic list back into an array
        theFilters.filter = theEntities.ToArray();

        // Here are your sales orders
        salesOrderShipmentEntity[] x =
            this.mageObject.MageService.salesOrderShipmentList(this.mageObject.MageSessionId, theFilters);
```

Answer (score 1):

I haven't done C# in 5 years, but here is what you need to do is don't set the `filterOrderId` as a `complex_filter`

This is the PHP equivalent of your code:

```
$filterOrderId = array(
    'key' => "order_increment_id",
    'value' => array("eq" => "100000044")
);
$filters = array(
    'complex_filter' => array($filterOrderId)
);

$client->salesOrderShipmentList($sessionId, $filters);
```

This produces the same error.
The following is a PHP call that works, so try to reproduce that data structure in C#:

```
$filterOrderId = array(
    'key' => "order_increment_id",
    'value' => array("eq" => "100000044")
);
$filters = array(0 => $filterOrderId);
// or: $filters = array($filterOrderId);

$client->salesOrderShipmentList($sessionId, $filters);
```

This works. You cold simplify the `filterOrderId` a little further, but thats not the cause of your problem.

```
$filterOrderId = array(
    'key' => "order_increment_id",
    'value' => "100000044"
);
```

**EDIT:** What works in PHP also is passing the `filterOrderId` to the `salesOrderShipmentList()` call directly.

```
$filterOrderId = array(
    'key' => "order_increment_id",
    'value' => "100000044"
);

$client->salesOrderShipmentList($sessionId, $filterOrderId);
```

Comment: This is a great suggestion thank you.
 I tried it with little luck. The Csharp syntax is strongly typed. It wants an object of type Filter and the Filter object wants an object of type ComplexFilter or AssociateFilter. I tried the AssociativeFilter using your last example's syntax without success.

Comment: How about setting Magento to run in WS-I compliant mode? The setting can be found unter System > Config > Magento Core API > WS-I Compliance. This will cause the WSDL to change, so you need to take care it isn't cached or something. Maybe that will enable you to pass in a working data structure to Magento.

Comment: Is the problem not as in Accepted Answer? You need to get the order_id first?

Answer (score 0):

Which magento version do you use? In my CE 1.6 filtering shipments, credit memos, invoices, etc. by fields from order (except order id) is not implemented yet. If you look at method `joinAttribute()` in `Mage_Sales_Model_Resource_Collection_Abstract` which is parent class to all shipments, credit memos, etc. collections - you will see:

```
/**
 * Backward compatibility with EAV collection
 *
 * @todo implement join functionality if necessary
 *
 * @param string $alias
 * @param string $attribute
 * @param string $bind
 * @param string $filter
 * @param string $joinType
 * @param int $storeId
 * @return Mage_Sales_Model_Resource_Collection_Abstract
 */
public function joinAttribute($alias, $attribute, $bind, $filter = null, $joinType = 'inner', $storeId = null)
{
    return $this;
}
```

Don't know though, maybe in latest CE 1.6.2 it is fixed already.

Comment: Thats not a bug, thats a backward compatibility leftover from Magento 1.3, when Mage_Sales entities where still EAV based. Now they are flat table based, so this EAV method is no longer needed. You get the order_increment_id even though it's not implemented.

Comment: @Vinai But it's not marked with "deprecated" annotation. And why is there a TODO annotation. If you had used the funcionality you will get problems and see no warning, error or an exception.

Comment: @cmuench I agree that it should either be marked as deprecated or implemented. but I can almost hear the thought process of the developer "I don't think this method is used, I'll just leave it out for now and see if we need to implement later". And of course it never was changed. To bad.

Answer (score 0):

> /**  * Backward compatibility with EAV collection  *  * @todo
>   implement join functionality if necessary

I think this is a severe bug in magento!

Doesn't throw any warning??
Where is the so called Backward compatibility?

Old Extensions that relies on this feature, arent working right and this may happen silently